# How should I deal with required models external to the Rails engine during development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I am extracting pieces of a Rails application into an engine. The engine contains model classes with relationships to model classes from the application in which the engine is mounted. In some cases, those relationships are required.

```
module Carrier
  class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :company_id
    belongs_to :company, class_name: Carrier.company_class_name
    validates :company, presence: true
  end
end
```

Since the engine does not have the `Company` class, how should this relationship be handled during development? What do other people do to "stub" the external classes?

Answer (score 2):

Create a model in the engine for the required class (`Company` in the example).

```
module Carrier
  class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

Add a migration that will only run in the Dummy app within the engine.

```
class CreateCarrierCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    if Rails.application.class.parent_name == "Dummy"
      create_table :carrier_companies do |t|
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Create the `mattr_accessor` and other methods in the engine Module so that it uses the stubbed class in development but the defined class otherwise.

```
module Carrier
  mattr_accessor :company_class_name
  def self.company_class_name
    @@company_class_name || "Carrier::Company"
  end
  def self.company_class
    company_class_name.constantize
  end  
end
```

You may want to raise an exception if the `company_class_name` is not set when the engine is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

For any migration and models in the main application, I copy the migrations in dummy app and define the empty model for same in the dummy app.